# How to modify the output of PowerShell Jobs if they take too long

Tags: powershell, jobs

I have a relatively long/complex script that blindly runs a batch of commands against several devices (as jobs).  Once in awhile, a couple of these jobs continue to run indefinitely.  I’ve added a **Wait-Job -Timeout** command to my script (see below) in order to force-stop jobs that are taking too long to run.

I’d like to change the output for these hung jobs to read *“This device is busy or unstable”*. How can I do this?  I'm guessing I need to add something to the tail-end of the pipeline (in the last line of code below).

```PoSH
$Jobs += Get-Job
$jobs | Wait-Job -Timeout 5 | out-null  

Get-Job | ? {$_.State -eq 'Running'} | Stop-Job -PassThru
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to iterate over the jobs that are currently running and write your message for each one:

```
$Jobs += Get-Job
$Jobs | Wait-Job -Timeout 5 | Out-Null

Get-Job | ? { $_.State -eq 'Running' } | Stop-Job -PassThru | % { Write-Host "This device is busy or unstable" }
```

You can also add info from the jobs that are being stopped, like the job ID for example:

```
Get-Job | ? { $_.State -eq 'Running' } | Stop-Job -PassThru | % { Write-Host "This device is busy or unstable: $($_.Id)" }
```

**UPDATE:** You can use a hashtable to store the job IDs that were "force stopped". Then iterate through the Jobs using Receive-Job to get the output, and check if the job is in the ForceStoppedIds table. If it is write your custom message, otherwise just output the message. Here's a simple test I ran.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Starting 1."; Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Write-Output "1 complete."; } | Out-Null
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Starting 2."; Start-Sleep -Seconds 60; Write-Output "2 complete."; } | Out-Null
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Starting 3."; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2; Write-Output "3 complete."; } | Out-Null
$Jobs += Get-Job
$Jobs | Wait-Job -Timeout 5 | Out-Null
$ForceStoppedIds = @{}
$Jobs | ? { $_.State -eq 'Running' } | Stop-Job -PassThru | % { $ForceStoppedIds[$_.Id] = $true }
foreach ($job in $Jobs) {
    $jobOutput = Receive-Job $job -Wait
    if ($ForceStoppedIds.Contains($job.Id)) {
        Write-Host "Custom message about stopped job: $($jobOutput)"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $jobOutput
    }
}
```

One thing to be cautious of is how jobs output information (ie. Write-Host, Write-Output, return, etc.). If you're not getting the results you expect, double check the job's ScriptBlock to see how the information is being written/returned/etc. I'm sure there are much more elegant ways of doing this, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: It looks like all that does is display a message for each job it stops.  Im looking for a way to modify the original Job Id's output so when I display the output of each job later in the script, the ones that were force-stopped, would say a custom message.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Have you tried/looked into [Receive-Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: Accidentally hit enter...haha wasn't finished writing. What about putting the jobs into two arrays? One for the jobs that you stop and one for the everything else. Then use Receive-Job on the arrays to get the job output(s) so you can use it and/or write your custom message.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to not display the "forced-stopped" jobs in a separate group from the rest of the devices.  I know this is being really picky, but I'm hoping for a way to maintain the same job order/sequence as they were first received in the original $jobs array.  These jobs almost always complete in the same order as they were first executed.  I'd like to keep it that way if at all possible.  Maybe you (or someone else) may know how to maintain the same job/sequence as in the original $jobs array.  I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the solution rootkow!  It worked like a charm